# Php namespace vs require

Tags: php, symfony

quick question, I'm playing with The HttpFoundation Component (Symfony) and something is not clear to me. The tutorial I'm looking at shows this code

```
// framework/index.php
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

$input = $request->get('name', 'World');

$response = new Response(sprintf('Hello %s', htmlspecialchars($input, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));

$response->send();
```

Now, this works, no problem, but I was trying to make it work without the 'use' keywords, so including (php require) the Request class itself, and then I get a class not found, which is so wierd to me, when I use the use keyword and use the namespace, the class is found, but when I include the classfile itself, I get a class not found..

So to illustrate, this returns a 'Class not found'..

```
// framework/index.php
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Request.php';

$request = new Request();
```

Can anyone clear this up for me please?
Thanks in advance!

P.S. I've red the use keyword is not including anything, just declaring the namespace or something? So It's so wierd to me that it works with the use case since its not even including files and when I include the file directly it returns a 'Class not found'...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `use`, you create something like an file based alias for the fully qualified name(fqn). So if you use `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request`, you could write `Request` instead of the fqn. If you dont want to include the use statement, you have to write everytime the whole class name.

```
// framework/index.php
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$request = \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::createFromGlobals();

$input = $request->get('name', 'World');

$response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response(sprintf('Hello %s', htmlspecialchars($input, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));

$response->send();
```

The `use`-statement itself has nothing to do with class loading. The class loading stuff is done by the autoloader which resolves the filename of the included php class out of it's class name.

To clear your question code up:

```
// framework/index.php
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Request.php';

$request = new Request();
```

The Class \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request is included, but you want to create an new object of the class \Request, which is something different.

Answer (score 3):

Namespace is not about loading classes, is about naming.

```
<?php
$response = new Response();
```

Here we're telling PHP to use a `\Response` class. So if a `\Response` class is not loaded at the moment, you'll get an error.

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

$response = new Response();
```

And here (with `new Response()` statement) we're telling it to use a `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response` class. So if a `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response` class is not loaded at the moment, you'll get an error.

Basically `use Some\Namespaced\ClassName` means `use Some\Namespaced\ClassName as ClassName`, think of it as aliasing in file context.

Read more at http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php .

Comment: @deceze That was for `new Response()` statement obviously. But I'll update, OK.

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate things:

1. loading (including, requiring) the actual source code file
2. aliasing names

`use` exclusively establishes an alias.
`use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;` is shorthand for
`use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request as Request;`,
which means the only thing it does is it allows you to refer to the class `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` (that's the class' actual fully qualified name) by the shorthand `Request`.

The loading of the source code file is taken care of by the autoloader the first time you try to do something with the class, like calling a method on it or instantiating it.

When you `require` the file manually, you've loaded the code (needlessly, since you're also loading the autoloader, which would take care of that for you), but you're not addressing the class by its actual fully qualified name, hence PHP has no idea what class you're talking about. The class' name is `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request`, not `Request`.